# Flutter navigator 2.0 page transition right to left and left to right not working

Tags: flutter, navigator

I'm implementing navigator 2.0 in my project with the help of https://github.com/orestesgaolin/navigator_20_example. But page transition, right to left and left to right in Android not working. I need screen transtion as explain here: https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/06/flutter-screen-navigation-custom-transition.html.